# How to disable natural scrolling in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, scrolling

I can't disable natural scrolling, and I have tried disabling and enabling it from the **Mouse and touch-pad** settings. I'm using GNOME Shell 3.24.1. I have already tried these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
```

I am a beginner in Ubuntu. Please suggest me step by step procedure to rectify this.

PS: My scrolling in the mouse is fine. The only problem is with the touch-pad.

`$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse                   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (170):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (172): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (300): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (301):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (302):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (303):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (323):  1659, 5337, 1531, 4401
    Synaptics Finger (324): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (325):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (326):   238
    Synaptics Tap Durations (327):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (328):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (329):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (330):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (331):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (332): 108, 108
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (333): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (334):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (335): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036880, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (336):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (337):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (338):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (339): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (340):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (341): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (342):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (343): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (344):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (345): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (346):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (347): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (348):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (349): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (350):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (351):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (352):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (353):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (354): 53, 36
    Synaptics Area (355):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (356):  3498, 0, 4033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (357): 27, 27
    Device Product ID (293):    2, 7
    Device Node (292):  "/dev/input/event7"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Screenshot Added.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput list-props 13`. PLEASE ADD IT AS TEXT, NOT AS A SCREENSHOT.

Comment: @Pilot6: Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 is supposed to use `libinput`, not `xorg-synaptics`.

Install `libinput` by

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Reboot or restart the session.

Answer (score 2):

In GNOME 17.04, the `Mouse & Touchpad` settings panel acts kind of funny. When first opened, it only shows the General and Mouse settings, and gives no indication that there's actually more to be seen. Point inside the settings panel and scroll your mouse wheel, and you'll see Touchpad settings appear, and there is a different Natural Scrolling setting for the mouse vs touchpad.

[image]

Comment: Seems like touchpad settings are not appearing in my case. Only mouse settings are here. :(

Comment: @Srijan did installing xserver-xorg-input-libinput allow this panel to display the touchpad settings?